# ORA-04052: error occurred when looking up remote object OWNER.FUNCTION_NAME@DB_LINK Oracle 11g to 10g

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, linked-server

I'm running an oracle 11g database that needs to run queries on a remote Oracle 10g database. To do this I created a database link on my 11g system. The link works fine with ordinary SQL queries. 
E.g: SELECT * FROM table_name@db_link work fine.

However, when I attempt to execute a procedure residing on the 10g system from the 11g, I get the following error:

ORA-04052: error occurred when looking up remote object OWNER_NAME.FUNCTION_NAME@DB_LINK
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06544: PL/SQL: internal error, arguments: [55916], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-06553: PLS-801: internal error [55916]
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from DB_LINK

The procedure is executed by the use of synonyms, I'm using PL/SQL Developer.

The 11g system is on Windows 7 while the 10g is on Solaris, if it's of any relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **apply patchset 10.2.0.3** in the 10g database.Kindly refer [this link for the similar issue](https://community.oracle.com/thread/611921?tstart=0)

Kindly download the patch set from metalink

**Patch 5337014 from metalink**

Comment: Thank you, that was actually the solution. It turns out there is a bug in 10g :(

Comment: Unfortunately, applying the patch is not an option. Downgraded the 11g to 10g instead. Thanks for the help anyway.